# AWS SQL Server RDS Command timeout issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are recently migrating to AWS.

We have millions of records in our Database.

We have Windows service built on .Net code that executes a proc again this DB.

Sometimes proc executes within seconds.

And sometimes we are seeing command time outs (from application set 40 mins) and all the further same proc calls to DB continues to timeout.
When I checked status of the process ID  (from SQL server profiler), it shows as suspended as other process is reading the data.

But when I execute the same proc call directly in Query analyzer with same  sql user account, it finished within seconds. (Don't know why we are seeing issue only with application making call to proc, as I am using same sql user id).

Our RDS multi-AZ.

Also our proc has `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`

Please suggest.

Comment: I'd start by examining RDS CloudWatch stats, especially I/O related. Do you use provisioned IOPS or general purpose SSD? The later supports [baseline / burst](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html) performance which might explain your status